# How do i merge the Facebook Connect with existing website's authentication?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, mojoportal

Im testing something on a MojoPortal where i need to seperately add a Facebook connect button and make the user get registered with the website's registration! How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a too late answer but it may help someone...

To login and register on mojo portal using fb, the easiest way is linking an OpenId, to obtain openId you must create an account in [JanRain](http://janrain.com/) and setup a fb application for grant access
the seccuence is this   mojoPortal-JainRain api- fb then the procees is forwback.

This is a complete tutorial [Using socialmedia to login MojoPortal](http://blog.arvixe.com/mojoportal-tip-one-step-mojoportal-registration-for-social-media-users/).

the only disadvantage is that the free account on JainRain limits the number of registers for month to 2000 I think. I hope this helps and sorry for my bad english XD